# Generating dynamic conditional form fields from JSON - AngularJS1.x

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, json

I am working on a AngularJS1.x application where I have to generate dynamic form fields based on some conditions. The entire dynamic form field type, field validations, conditions are coming from a JSON. The field type can be textboxes, select boxes, date-pickers, radio buttons or check boxes.

Trying to Accomplish:
I am trying to work on a simpler process to generate the form fields based on the conditions.

For each field type there are 3 conditions,

- `is_mandatory`
- `is_editable`
- `is_display`

Their values can be,

- 0 (No)
- 1 (Yes)
- 2 (Conditional)

For example,

```
is_display : 1, is_editable : 2, is_mandatory : 0
```

This means that a **field will be visible**, **will be editable based on a certain condition** and **it is not a mandatory field**.
For this field as the editable property a condition based, it will check another property called, `editable_condition` which holds a value like,

`editable_condition : 1.1. Introductory Questions|111_what_is_the_inspection_typ|Onsite`

The value in between the `|` separated value is the **unique_id**, i.e., `111_what_is_the_inspection_typ in this case`

This **unique_id** represents another field, if that field value matches with the last `|` separated value, i.e., `Onsite` in this case, of this field then this field will be editable.

Here is a screenshot of the JSON,
[image]

Now my question is what will be the best possible way to handle such conditions to display the different types of fields like the checkboxes, radio buttons, textboxes, datepickers and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to reinvent the wheel have you considered using a library such as [angular-formly](http://angular-formly.com/).

This would allow you to declaratively specify the form via JSON e.g.

HTML

```
<formly-form model="vm.user" fields="vm.userFields">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="vm.submit(vm.user)">Submit</button>
</formly-form>
```

JS

```
function YourCtrl() {
  var vm = this;

  vm.user = {};

  vm.userFields = [
    {
      key: 'email',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'email',
        label: 'Email address',
        placeholder: 'Enter email'
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'password',
      type: 'input',
      templateOptions: {
        type: 'password',
        label: 'Password',
        placeholder: 'Password'
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'file',
      type: 'file',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'File input',
        description: 'Example block-level help text here',
        url: 'https://example.com/upload'
      }
    },
    {
      key: 'checked',
      type: 'checkbox',
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Check me out'
      }
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: The JSON I am using is coming from the back end. How will I convert that into the respective JSON format as per the library, angular-formly.

Comment: Client side, you would have to write a helper to convert your proprietary JSON format into its formly equivalent.